# Is the product of two independent uniform integrable random variable is uniform integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-integrability

Is the product of two independent uniform integrable random variable is uniform integrable? What is the role independence plays here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(Y_i)_{i\in I}$ are two families of random variables such that

- for each $i\in I$, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent;
- the family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is uniformly integrable;
- the family $(Y_i)_{i\in I}$ is uniformly integrable,

then the family $(X_iY_i)$ is uniformly integrable.

To see that, notice that $\{|X_iY_i|\gt R\}\subset \{|X_i|\gt \sqrt R\}\cup\{|Y_i|\gt \sqrt R\}$, hence 
$$\int_{\{|X_iY_i|\gt R\}}|X_iY_i|\mathrm d\mu\leqslant \int_{\{|X_i|\gt \sqrt R\}}|X_i||Y_i|\mathrm d\mu+\int_{\{|Y_i|\gt \sqrt R\}}|X_i||Y_i|\mathrm d\mu.$$
Using now independence, we obtain 
$$\int_{\{|X_i|\gt \sqrt R\}}|X_i||Y_i|\mathrm d\mu=\mathbb E|Y_i|\cdot \int_{\{|X_i|\gt \sqrt R\}}|X_i|\mathrm d\mu\leqslant \sup_{j\in I}\mathbb E|Y_j|\cdot \int_{\{|X_i|\gt \sqrt R\}}|X_i|\mathrm d\mu$$
and we conclude since $\sup_{j\in I}\mathbb E|Y_j|$ is finite.